# Kubuntu cannot start normally

Tags: boot, kubuntu, screen, kde

- Kubuntu 12.10 64 bit was installed in my laptop (Thinkpad T430)

### Problems:

The first time I restart the Kubuntu after the installation is fine except the Kubuntu logo with gray background picture wasn't showed while starting and shutting down instead of showing the current status(loading or killing something), it doesn't concern me, but **everything goes wrong after the restart after some software upgraded, the system just shuts the screen down after booting***(if it's a black screen, you can still see some light out from the screen, my laptop doesn't release any light at all, so I guess the screen was shut down).*

### I tried:

However, I can still start Kubuntu through "Advanced options for Ubuntu" -> "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0.17-generic", but when I go to "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0.27-generic" it behaves exactly same as choose "Ubuntu" directly(turns screen off).

I'm using Kubuntu through "3.5.0.17-generic", I tried to install kdm and chose kdm as default login way, it doesn't change anything (I'm new to Linux, I don't know if it is good to try this).

### The help I need:

1. What are the meanings of "Linux 3.5.0.17-generic" and "Linux 3.5.0.27-generic", what are the differences between these two options?
2. how can I start Kubuntu by choose "Ubuntu" instead of choose "Advanced options for Ubuntu" -> "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0.17-generic"?

Thanks for any advice and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. They are two different kernel versions and there is no noticeable difference between them
2. Remove the newer version of the kernel and stop it from updating:

   1. Hit Alt + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `konsole` into the box at the top of the screen that appeared
   2. Copy:

      ```
      sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.5.0.27-generic linux-headers-3.5.0.27-generic ;sudo apt-mark hold linux-image linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic
      ```

   Into the new window hit enter, type in your password; if it asks you if you want to do this type `yes` in the window.